# How to center one of two flex items in a flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want box 2 to be in the center of the `#box-cntnr` so I'm using the `align-self` property. I'd be open to other approaches on accomplishing this. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x1y71hh5/).

### HTML

```
<div id="box-cntnr">
  <div class="box" id="b1">box 1</div>
  <div class="box" id="b2">box 2</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 10px;
}

#box-cntnr {
  display: flex;
}

#b1 {
  align-self: center;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want BOX #2 centered both vertically and horizontally in the flex container, the first thing you would need to do is give the container some height.

In your code, the flex item could only center horizontally because the container has no height specified, so it resolves to content height and the vertical space is limited.

**HTML** (no changes)

**CSS**

```
html, body { height: 100%; }

body { margin: 0; }

#box-cntnr {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 10px;
}

#b2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/x1y71hh5/1/)

Flex alignment properties such as `justify-content`, `align-items`, `align-self` and `auto` margins work by distributing the free space in the flex container. So if BOX #2 were the only flex item in the container, we could use these properties for perfect centering.

However, BOX #2 has a sibling (BOX #1), so these properties cannot be used effectively for centering as BOX #1 is occupying space, and that will throw off the calculation. In other words, flex alignment properties will center BOX #2 in the *remaining space*.

The easiest way around this is with [absolute positioning](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items). We can apply `position: relative` to the container and `position: absolute` to BOX #2. This removes BOX #2 from the document flow and enables us to align it freely within the entire space of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this....and add 
like this

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 10px;
}

#box-cntnr {
  display: flex;
}

#b1 {
  align-self: center;
}
.ctr1 {
  margin:0 auto;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-cntnr">
<div class="ctr1">
  <div class="box" id="b1">box 1</div>
  <div class="box" id="b2">box 2</div>
</div>
</div>
```